# How to read controls from custom template add on code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I need to generate columns which contains checkbox based on data stored in database (this grid can have different number of columns per month)

I've got this code with custom template on my grid view control:

**aspx part:**

```
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="bt_save_top" OnClick="bt_save_Click" Text="Save" />
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv_result" AutoGenerateColumns="false" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1" RowStyle-BorderWidth="1" RowStyle-BorderStyle="Solid">
        </asp:GridView>
```

***cs :**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var ds = new DataSet();//getting data from database
        var weekDayColumns = GenerateColumns(ds);
        foreach (DataControlField dataControlField in weekDayColumns)
        {
            gv_result_tw.Columns.Add(dataControlField);
        }
        gv_result_tw.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        gv_result_tw.DataBind();
    }
    private DataControlFieldCollection GenerateColumns(DataSet dsTable)
    {
        var columns = new DataControlFieldCollection();
        foreach (DataColumn column in dsTable.Tables[0].Columns)
        {
            var itemTemplate = new TemplateField
            {
                HeaderText = column.Caption,
                ControlStyle =
                {
                    CssClass = "gv_row"
                },
                HeaderStyle =
                {
                    CssClass = "gv_row"
                },
                ItemTemplate = new CustomItemTemplate(ListItemType.Item, column.ColumnName)
            };
            columns.Add(itemTemplate);
        }

        return columns;
   }

    protected void bt_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         foreach(var row in gv_result_tw.Rows) 
         {
              var columnNameField = gvr.FindControl("hidden_time") as HiddenField; 
             // Here i'm getting always null
         }
    }
```

**CustomItemTemplate.cs**

```
public class CustomItemTemplate : ITemplate
    {
        private readonly ListItemType _type;
        private readonly string _columnName;
        public ItemTemplateGenerator(ListItemType t, string columnName)
        {
            _type = t;
            _columnName = columnName;
        }

        // Override InstantiateIn() method
        void ITemplate.InstantiateIn(Control container)
        {
            switch (_type)
            {
                case ListItemType.Item:
                    var visibleCheckbox = new CheckBox
                    {
                        ID = $"chb_{_columnName.Replace(":", "_")}_visible"
                    };
                    visibleCheckbox.DataBinding += VisibleCheckbox_DataBinding;

                    var invisibleField = new HiddenField
                    {
                        ID = $"chb_{_columnName.Replace(":", "_")}_invisible"
                    };
                    var hiddenInput = new HiddenField
                    {
                        ID = $"hidden_time",
                        Value = _columnName
                    };
                    container.Controls.Clear();
                    container.Controls.Add(hiddenInput);
                    container.Controls.Add(visibleCheckbox);
                    container.Controls.Add(invisibleField);
                    break;
            }
        }
        // The DataBinding event of your controls
        private void VisibleCheckbox_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var checkBox = (CheckBox)sender;
            var container = (GridViewRow)checkBox.NamingContainer;
            var hiddenField = (HiddenField)checkBox.NamingContainer.FindControl($"chb_{_columnName.Replace(":","_")}_invisible");
            var bindValue = DataBinder.Eval(container.DataItem, _columnName);
            // Adding check in case Column allows null values
            if (bindValue != DBNull.Value)
            {
                hiddenField.Value = bindValue.ToString();
                checkBox.Checked = bindValue.ToString() == "1";
            }
        }
    }
```

So the question is how I should done this "FindControl" to get proper field instead of null?

If you need more details please just ask.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make two changes, one in the `InstantiateIn` implementation of your CustomItemTemplate so the container gets an ID as well. In this case I picked the value of `_columnName`:

```
public class CustomItemTemplate : ITemplate
{
    // stuff omitted for brevity     

    // Override InstantiateIn() method
    void ITemplate.InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        // set the ID of the container these fields are in!
        container.ID = _columnName;
        // rest of your code
        // make sure hidden_time is still unique!
        var hiddenInput = new HiddenField
            {
                ID = $"{_columnName.Replace(":", "_")}_hidden_time",
                Value = _columnName
            };
    }
}
```

Then your button click implementation can leverage that ID when it sets off to find the control:

```
protected void bt_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // a GridViewRow has cells ...
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gv_result_tw.Rows)
    {
        // ... the cells are of type DataControlFieldCell
        foreach (DataControlFieldCell col in row.Cells)
        {
            // ... but we get some bonus fields as well 
            if (col.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                // .. if we skip those 
                // ... we get a cell that has its ID set to the value
                // that was used to generate the ID of the hiddenfield
                var columnNameField = row.FindControl(col.ID + "_hidden_time") as HiddenField;
               // columnNameField will not be null now ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```